# Multi Tail UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, tail

I'm trying to multi tail files using tail -F file1 file2

The output is like this

File1
text from file 1
text from file 1
text from file 1
text from file 1

File2
text from file 2
text from file 2
text from file 2

File1
text from file 1
text from file 1
text from file 1

Is it possible to append the file name to the stream as well ?

example

file1 text from file 1
file2 text from file 2
file1 text from file 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the `tail` output through `awk`:

```
tail -F file1 file2 file3 | awk '/^==>/{f=$2;next} NF>0{print f"  "$0}'
```

Comment: @j.w.r : can you explain in your post how this awk works exactly ?